# Is $HOME/.local/share the default value for $XDG_DATA_HOME?

Tags: environment-variables, xdg, xdg-base-directory

What's the default value for `$XDG_DATA_HOME` variable? I get an empty line with:

```
echo $XDG_DATA_HOME
```

According to the [Free Desktop XDG Base Directory Environment variables specification](https://specifications.freedesktop.org/basedir-spec/basedir-spec-latest.html#variables), it might be equal to `$HOME/.local/share`?

Comment: Same here. Seems not to be set.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As report in [XDG Base Directory Specification environment variables aren't set by default](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xdg-user-dirs/+bug/1122613) bug, Ubuntu doesn't set XDG variables.

According to [FreeDesktop Base Directory Specification](http://standards.freedesktop.org/basedir-spec/basedir-spec-latest.html):

> $XDG_DATA_HOME defines the base directory relative to which user
>   specific data files should be stored. If $XDG_DATA_HOME is either not
>   set or empty, a default equal to $HOME/.local/share should be used.

Applications that implement this specification must implement this behaviour, so if `$XDG_DATA_HOME` is not defined they must use `$HOME/.local/share` as default.

There are some implementation of this specification, like: [Glib](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/2.30/glib-Miscellaneous-Utility-Functions.html#g-get-user-config-dir), [libghc-xdg-basedir-prof](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/raring/libghc-xdg-basedir-prof/) and [pyxdg](http://freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/pyxdg/)

If you want to override this value, you should define `XDG` variable in `/etc/profile` or better in `/etc/profile.d` as described in [Where should the XDG_CONFIG_HOME variable be defined?](https://superuser.com/questions/365847/where-should-the-xdg-config-home-variable-be-defined)

Answer (score 7):

If it's unset, you can set it thus in your `~/.profile`:

```
export XDG_DATA_HOME=${XDG_DATA_HOME:="$HOME/.local/share"}
```

This keeps any value already set, else sets it to the default value specified in the [XDG Base Directory Specification](https://specifications.freedesktop.org/basedir-spec/basedir-spec-latest.html)

Comment: Better to define this in your `~/.xprofile`, or as the accepted answer suggests `/etc/profile`. If your default shell is zsh, you may also get by using your `~/.zshenv` file because everything will read that file

Comment: Yeah, I agree it depends heavily on which Linux distribution we are concerned with. For Arch the choice is obviously `.xprofile` at `$HOME`...

Comment: Better yet, `~/.profile` for both `{ba,z}sh` and console logins also. Answer updated