# Where is the setting that tells the desktop to look in ~/.local/share?

Tags: ubuntu-gnome, xdg-base-directory

I had some issues and tried to reset my Ubuntu desktop back to defaults, but the results were poor.  After comparing all the settings side by side with a fresh Ubuntu install, I got it back to about 95%, but one issue still lingers...my custom .desktop files aren't appearing in the applications view.  When I bring it up I see the icons that got installed system-wide, but the ones in ~/.local/share/applications aren't there.

If I launch one via gtk-launch, it starts up fine and behaves as expected, and I can pin it to my dock.

Editing the file info, such as the title, is reflected immediately.

```
g051051@ubuntu:~$ env | grep XDG
XDG_CONFIG_DIRS=/etc/xdg/xdg-ubuntu:/etc/xdg
XDG_MENU_PREFIX=gnome-
XDG_SESSION_DESKTOP=ubuntu
XDG_SESSION_TYPE=x11
XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP=ubuntu:GNOME
XDG_SESSION_CLASS=user
XDG_RUNTIME_DIR=/run/user/1000
XDG_DATA_DIRS=/usr/share/ubuntu:/usr/local/share/:/usr/share/
```

What magic setting am I missing?

Edit: I meant ~/.local/share, not shared.

Comment: I don't see a `XDG_DATA_HOME` - it should default to `$HOME/.local/share` (not share*d*) according to the [XDG Base Directory Specification](https://specifications.freedesktop.org/basedir-spec/basedir-spec-latest.html). Where exactly that happens may depend on the desktop session.

Comment: XDG_DATA_HOME isn't set in my reference system, either.  Everything works fine there...I created a simple .desktop file and it showed up as expected.

Comment: Maybe an answer might help in https://askubuntu.com/a/538590/231142

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is $HOME/.local/share the default value for $XDG\_DATA\_HOME in Ubuntu 14.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/538526/is-home-local-share-the-default-value-for-xdg-data-home-in-ubuntu-14-04)

Comment: @Terrance (and N0rbert) Those both link to the same answer page.  I had found that previously, and setting the env variable explicitly as described didn't help.  In addition, the working reference system doesn't have that value set either.